Screen is rapidly flashing when in a fullscreen application
I have had a glitch on my laptop where sometimes when I enter a fullscreen application the screen starts flashing a bright white. I can't find anyone else who's experienced this issue and have no clue where to start on debugging it. the only hint I could find is that whenever I change the brightness the screen will stop flashing temporarily. A reboot fixes it, but it is super annoying. I have swapped out SSDs and completely reinstalled Linux, but despite that the glitch persists.
There are two forms, one where the screen flashes between regular and completely white, and a form where it flashes between regular and a monochromatic version which highlights borders on objects. This is the second, weirder form of it.

   Ubuntu version: 22.04.04
   Display: Wayland
   GNOME Version: 42.9
   CPU: Ryzen 5 7640u
   Memory: 16GB
   Storage: 2TB SSD

@guiverc my version is 22.04.04 with wayland and GNOME 42.9. I have a ryzen 5 7640u with 16gb of ram and a 2tb ssd. I installed using a USB and the startup disk creator
